# Parsing logstash Custom Format -- Any Suggestion

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-forwarder

I get a response in response field of nginx different at different times .. The response is not fixed . It is in nested type many times

Sometimes it will be like

```
{"resp":{\x22code\x22:200,\x22message\x22:\x22success\x22},"field2":"IP","field3":0.006,"field4":"06758e99be484fca56fb","field5":200,"field6":"-","date":"Wednesday, 24-Feb-2016 10:10:12 GMT","method":"POST","field7":"somevaibale","scheme":"http","field8":"-","bytes":68, "field9":"Variable","timestamp":"2016-02-24 10:10:12.000"}
```

Some times the same Field1 can be different - Can you suggest what can be done here

```
{"resp":{\x22code\x22:200,\x22message\x22:\x22success\x22,\x22totalPages\x22:3,\x22data\x22:[{\x22items\x22:[{somedata | :{:{}},{:{}},{:{}},{:{}},{:{}},{:{}},{:{}},{:{}},{:{}},{:{}},{:{}},{:{}{}]}},"field2":"IP","field3":0.006,"field4":"06758e99be484fca56fb","field5":200,"field6":"-","date":"Wednesday, 24-Feb-2016 10:10:12 GMT","method":"POST","field7":"somevaibale","scheme":"http","field8":"-","bytes":68, "field9":"Variable","timestamp":"2016-02-24 10:10:12.000"}
```

So what can be done in logstash -- when i try to parse with grok pattern the nested field in resp .Gets failed for Grok parse failure and also if i try to use json filter it fails as the nested part does not fit.. Please let me know

Comment: Using the json filter with json seems like a good idea. What does "does not fit" mean?

Comment: @AlainCollins ?? IT does not fit means the Field1 does not have static pattern , The response in that field is dynamic .. in both the example in first example the response is one key value .. But doesnot parse the second one where the response is nested

Answer (score -1):

I found the for any custom format you can use the existing format - 
Below site is helpful  when it comes to parsing

https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/patterns#

and to parse use the pattern and source  below

https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Happy parsing ..